# Using tapply on data with NAs

Tags: r

I have a data column (Percent.Plant.Parasites) that has some NAs.  I want to take the mean of this data sorted by factor "Stage" (ie stage1 Mean=x, stage2 Mean=y, etc).  I tried doing this using

```
tapply(rawdata$Percent.Plant.Parasites, rawdata$Stage, mean)
```

However, I get NAs because there are NAs in the data.  I don't believe there is an na.rm option for tapply (is there?), so I tried to calculate the mean of each individual stage factor using:

```
mean(subset(rawdata,subset=Stage=="stage1")$Percent.Plant.Parasites, na.rm=TRUE)
```

to no avail.  Instead I got the error:

```
In mean.default(subset(rawdata, subset = Stage == "Kax")$Percent.Plant.Parasites,  :
```

argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

However, when I do:

```
typeof(subset(rawdata,subset=Stage=="Kax")$Percent.Plant.Parasites)
```

I get `integer`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `mean(subset(rawdata, Stage=="stage1")$Percent.Plant.Parasites, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: The structure of `tapply` is: `tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)`. You can try to specify `na.rm = TRUE` in the `...` parameter like this: `tapply(rawdata$Percent.Plant.Parasites, rawdata$Stage, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: what is `class(rawdata$Percent.Plant.Parasites)`?  I'm betting it's 'factor', in which case, you probably need to call `rawdata$Percent.Plant.Parasites <- as.numeric(as.character(Percent.Plant.Parasites))`

Comment: Thanks all.  I wound up getting around the problem using ddply and summarize.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a new function, call it mean_NA, that simply removes the NAs before calculating the mean and then use that function in tapply? Something like:

```
mean_NA<-function(v){
    avg<-mean(v, na.rm = T)
return (avg)
}
```

As was commented, make sure that the data you're taking the mean of is numeric/integer and the INDEX is factor(groups). You would use the newly created function like this:

```
tapply(X = rawdata$Percent.Plant.Parasites, INDEX = rawdata$Stage, mean_NA)
```